# Assert.assertEquals didn't compares String right way

Tags: java, junit

I'm currently working on a udemy java programming class and struggling with an excercise.

Here the master soultion:

```
public class Bonbon {
    
    public static void bonbonRechner(){
        //Hier den Code der Main-Methode einfügen
        String Jan = "Jan";
        String Lisa = "Lisa";
        String Tom = "Tom";
        int Bonbons = 100;
        int JanBonbon = 6;
        int LisaBonbon = 11;
        int TomBonbon = 8;
        Bonbons = Bonbons - JanBonbon - LisaBonbon - TomBonbon;

        System.out.println(Jan + ": " + JanBonbon + ", " + Lisa + ": " + LisaBonbon + ", "
            + Tom + ": " + TomBonbon + ", Restlichen Bonbons: " + Bonbons);
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bonbonRechner();
    }
}
```

It should print `Jan: 6, Lisa: 11, Tom: 8, Restlichen Bonbons:75`

I configured the Evaluate.java like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import com.udemy.ucp.*;
import com.udemy.ucp.IOHelper;

public class Evaluate {
    Bonbon bw = new Bonbon();
    IOHelper helper = new IOHelper();
    @Test
    public void testExercise() {
        helper.resetStdOut();
        bw.bonbonRechner();
        Assert.assertEquals("Not right", 
            "Jan: 6, Lisa: 11, Tom: 8, Restlichen Bonbons: 75", helper.getOutput());
    }
}
```

This is what my console says:

```
Console

Not right expected:<...stlichen Bonbons: 75[]> but was:<...stlichen Bonbons: 75[

Your output

Jan: 6, Lisa: 11, Tom: 8, Restlichen Bonbons: 75

]>
```

Any ideas how I can fix the problem with the missing ]> in my output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is that `IOHelper` is capturing extra output, where it says "Your output" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.println` appends a new line `\n` after your text, which is part of the comparison as everything of StdOut is captured by your IOHelper, but your expected String does not contain a new line. You could use `System.out.print` instead to avoid this.